# How to find specific csv files and extract their second row into a single csv file

Tags: sed, awk, csv

I'm trying to find out how to filter specific csv files by name and then extract their second row into a single csv file. I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to find files and then pipe it with commands like sed/awk to extract desired line.

```
find -name "data.csv" | sed -n 2p > final.csv
```

## update

Using a for loop in bash script generates desired output but prints all output in a single line.

```
for OUTPUT in $(find -name "data.csv")
do

        sed -n 2p $OUTPUT

done
```

Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: Why are you appending "`\n`"? The shell sees that as "`n`", and passes it on to `sed`, which interprets that as the name of an input file. And then, as you see, it complains that there's no file or directory called "n".

Comment: Yeah, it was silly try!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output of `find -name "data.csv"`, you'll see that it prints the full pathnames of files named `data.csv`. The pipeline passes that on to `sed`, which prints the second line of its input.

So what you're saying is, "Here's a list of files. Give me the second one one the list." What you really want to say is "Here's a list of files. For each one, give me the second line." And for that, you want to use `xargs`.

Most likely, you'll need

```
find -name "data.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -n 2p > final.csv
```

It's often a good idea to use `find -print0 | xargs -0`: the `-print0` causes `find` to use NUL characters as separators between filenames instead of a newline, and `-0` tells `xargs` to expect this. This prevents filenames with spaces, returns, or other weird characters from messing up  your pipeline.

The `-n 1` tells `xargs` to run a separate `sed` process for each "data.csv" file it finds, rather than trying to batch them together, which usually makes things more efficient. In this case, if you run

```
sed -n 2p file1 file2 file3
```

it'll internally concatenate all of its input files into one input stream, and print the second line of that. But RTFM: there may be a way to make `sed` not do that, that I've missed.

Comment: thanks for this solution but it still prints all results in a single line.

Comment: Is it possible that the files you're finding only have two lines, and don't end with a newline?

Answer (score 0):

The result of the find is the list of filenames that sed needs to act upon.  Thus use xargs to execute sed on that list, one by one. But because filenames can contains spaces and newlines even, better use the "-print0" option of find, to delimit the filenames with ascii zero. Also, when those files are big, you can save cpu-heat by stopping after line 2.  And then you get:

```
find -name "data.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -n -e 2p -e 2q > final.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
find -name "data.csv" | xargs -n 1 sed -n 2p >> final.csv
```

Note above that using  `>>`  concatenates results from sed into final.csv, on a new line, instead of replacing them, whereas  `>`  simply replaces content in final.csv with output from sed.

Comment: thanks but prints the output in a single line